# Discord.py Python economy bot with mongodb "NoneType" error

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, discord.py, pymongo

(bad english)
I wanna create a economy bot with **mongodb**, it worked fine 2 days ago but now I have "NoneType" error

Sorce code from **main.py**(to add user in db):

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'''
[*]BOT: ON
[*]BOT NAME : {client.user}
[*]BOT ID: {client.user.id}
        ''')
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            post = {
                "_id": member.id,
                "balance": 10000000,
                "xp": 0,
                "level": 1
            }
            if collection.count_documents({"_id": member.id}) == 0:
                collection.insert_one(post)
```

That code is working because I see that on db

Source code from cog with problem:

```
class Economic(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.cluster  = MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://discord:{secret}@cluster403.xn9cm.mongodb.net/discord1?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
        cluster  = MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://discord:{secret}@cluster403.xn9cm.mongodb.net/users?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
        self.collection = cluster.users.tutu
    @commands.command(
        name = "balance",
        aliases = ["ball","money"],
        brief = "User balance",
        usage = "balance <@user>",
        description = "none....."
    )
    async def user_balace(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        if member is None:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = f"__{ctx.author}__'s balance",
                description = f"Money: {self.collection.find_one({'_id': ctx.author.id})['balance']}"
            )
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When I type ">balance" command in console I get that error:

```
Ignoring exception in command balance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nick403\Desktop\Apps\PROJECTS\BOT\cogs\eco.py", line 22, in user_balace
    description = f"Money: {self.collection.find_one({'_id': ctx.author.id})['balance']}"
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Can somebody help me ? (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is essentially saying that `self.collection.find_one({'_id': ctx.author.id})` is returning as `None`. In the [`PyMongo` Documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one), we can see that `find_one()` will return `None` when no such item is found in the collection. I would rewrite your code to have a safety in the event of not having a specific user in your database.

```
if self.collection.find({'_id': ctx.author.id}).count() == 0:
    self.collection.insert_one({USER OBJECT})

user = self.collection.find_one({'_id': ctx.author.id})
```